# Pentaho Reporting with NODEJS and without TOMCAT

Tags: java, node.js, tomcat, pentaho

I have a linux-based nodejs web application that I need to generate reports from and I have chosen Pentaho for this.

I have installed biserver-ce (5.4) which works, however this is an overkill as it uses tomcat which is a behemoth and uses huge amounts of CPU and memory (1.5GB+) which I don't have a lot of, and furthermore I do not require any user console, user management or security etc etc or any of the other features that biserver offers.

Currently the requests are sent to biserver:8080 by nodejs back-end and the resulting pdf report is then piped to the client's front-end browser using nodejs.

As far as I understand, tomcat is simply converting a http request and returning the rendered pdf, and since I already have a web server with nodejs this seems a bit redundant, and I want to bypass tomcat entirely.

So I am looking to eliminate tomcat and either have a server listening on a socket or simply send the report parameters via the command line, but having googled this for the last half day, I am still unable to find a definitive answer or example of how I can generate pentaho reports without using tomcat.

Can this be done ? I have good javascript skills but zero java programming abilities, Can I use just the parts of biserver that generate the reports and eliminate tomcat completely ?

I have moved the compiling issue to a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear possible to at least embed the reporting engine into a standalone Java application. This does require you to have some knowledge about Java and the Pentaho SDK, but it may be your only non-Tomcat option. There is a complete example Java project [here](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-reporting/tree/master/engine/samples) that shows you how to accomplish this (code is mostly in [Sample1.java](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-reporting/blob/master/engine/samples/source/org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/samples/Sample1.java)).

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have attempted to compile as above Updates but it's failing with 3 errors - any ideas ?

Comment: Have you compiled AbstractReportGenerator.java and set your `CLASSPATH` environment variable to include the directory that AbstractReportGenerator.class is in?

Comment: Thanks, yes, already compiled to same folder as the Sample1.java file and exported the path "export CLASSPATH=/Users/xxx/java-dev/pentaho:/Users/xxx/java-dev/pentaho/lib" but it makes no difference, error is identical